# zsh stopped parsing ~/.zshrc

Tags: macos, login, zsh

I'm running the latest OSX on an MBP from '11.

I've installed the latest zsh from macports and all of a sudden it stopped parsing the .zsh. Whenever I login I need to `source ~/.zshrc` before any binaries installed through macports are available.

Has anyone seen the same?

Comment: How are you running zsh - if Terminal what command does it run?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. zsh is my login shell so .zshrc should be run whenever I open Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by [RVM](http://rvm.io/). I uninstalled RVM and the problem disappeared.